# Code is unreachable - React Native in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, react-native

I'm new to React and I'm trying to build a simple project, but Visual Studio Pro tells me that the below code is "unreachable". It does compile though and I can see the result in the Android simulator as expected. What should I do to fix this?

**View in Visual Studio Pro 2019:**

[image]

**The whole code:**

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Hello React Native!!</Text>
            <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to this question myself. With a bit of messing around I believe I found it, although it may not be best practice.

Add a **jsconfig.json** file at the root folder and add the config

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react", // This flag is a must
    "checkJs": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": true // This removes some more warning lines
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I also had to change all my javascript files from .js to **.jsx**

Visual Studio will create the project using the simple javascript extension but from looking online the .jsx is the correct extension for react js as it allows both to work together. A little like a .cshtml file using MVC.

The first line from [What is a .jsx](https://www.reactenlightenment.com/react-jsx/5.1.html)

> JSX is an XML/HTML-like syntax used by React that extends ECMAScript so that XML/HTML-like text can co-exist with JavaScript/React code.

Hope this works for anyone else in need but it has worked for me with no errors showing in dev tools.